# D2L Dropbox - Posting issue

Tags: desire2learn

I'm getting an error trying to post a file to the dropbox in D2L. I'm using HttpRequest in PHP. The Org ID and Folder ID are both valid - I am retrieving the folder ID from the API (using the OrgID).

Here is the HttpRequest output:

```
POST /d2l/api/le/1.1/61381/dropbox/folders/677320/submissions/mysubmissions/?x_a=d0RNh1RjRGSMJu-dyj_wmw&x_b=_098IyP4bzkow_G-7Ke4Dv&x_c=3_L5VOX5RarK7mztTyX67sL_TyceBOK5r18GnRu9VbE&x_d=jVPR_DXuVf1JIl-YLe3Ad_OM2Ph8xG8UiMYriJVRc2w&x_t=1350769323 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PECL::HTTP/1.6.1-dev (PHP/5.2.6)
Host: <hostname>
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=65ace1fa6e1f
Content-Length: 251

--65ace1fa6e1f
Content-type: application/json

{"Text":"test","HTML":null}
--65ace1fa6e1f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="file.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

eyAiVGVztCI6IlRsaXMgfXMgdGVzdYBkYXRhLiIgfQ==
--65ace1fa6e1f--
```

And the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 131
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /d2l/error/404
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 20 Oct 2012 21:42:26 GMT
```

It appears to be a 404 (No such dropbox folder, or no such org unit), but I know both values to be valid.

I've logged into D2L and the OrgID and DropboxID are both correct in the URL when I'm editing the dropbox settings. The user in question has permission to access the dropbox, and can do so in D2L.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some things to try: Have you tried a GET through the API for that orgId and folderId combination -- will the GET call retrieve the DropboxFolder structure? Have you tried making the call against the v1.0 LE route? Have you tried uploading the data with a Content-Type of 'text/plain' to match your declared file extension instead of 'application/octet-stream'? I doubt any of these are the problem... You might want to open an issue with the Valence issue tracker for this; your example doesn't look any different to the answer for 'Submitting a file to Desire2Learn Dropbox'...

Comment: You should definitely follow up by contacting the Valence issue tracker: I've succeeded in posting a submission to a dropbox against our test instance, from a student user context, with a request looking very much like yours.

Comment: Thanks Viktor. I agree with your comments that it's unlikely to be any of the above. I modeleted my attempts after the post you reference. I've found the responses to tickets for Valence to be very slow of late - I have a ticket outstanding for over two months at present!

That being said, the orgID and dropboxID are correct - I can retrieve the folder contents from them with an API call.

Comment: I sympathize with the speed at which we can work through the tickets; on the other hand, our communication channel with the ticketing system is much richer than here (and it should be). It would help if you opened a ticket to send us a wireshark or fiddler dump of your request packet so we can have a look at exactly what's going out over the wire.

Comment: Is it possible that you need to be making this call through HTTPS? Your code sample shows it using HTTP. Our dev reports that the 302 redirecting to a 404 error page looks odd: this would seem to indicate that you're not even connecting to the API service layer for some reason... (if the route weren't found, the result would be a direct 404, and perhaps not a 302 redirecting to a 404 error page?)

Comment: 302 redirecting to 404 seems to be the standard response that I get when there's something wrong with the request. In one case, for example, my error was simply surrounding a json with square brackets resulting in this response.

Comment: Surrounding a JSON structure with square brackets would imply a JSON array containing a list of JSON items. Depending on the context, this would very likely produce an error of one kind or another.